# How to call ajax only the specific field made changes using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the ajax call function for update the data.In this all delivered_qty fields are updating when calling updateData() function.Instead of that i need to update only the specific field(delivered_qty) if it is not match the criteria.Now  within this condition if (!match) {} all fields are updating.
how to update only the particular field if it is not match instead of updating all the fields?

```
function updateData() { //update data
    var delivered_qty = [];
    var delivered_status = [];
    var deli_qtydbvalue = [];

    $('.delivered_status').each(function() {
        delivered_status.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('.delivered_qty').each(function() {
        delivered_qty.push($(this).val());
        deli_qtydbvalue.push($(this).attr('orginaldbvalue'));
    });

    var match = (delivered_qty.length == deli_qtydbvalue.length) && delivered_qty.every(function(element, index) {
        return element === deli_qtydbvalue[index];
    });

    if (!match) { 
        $.get("updatedeliverystatus.php", {
            delivered_qty: delivered_qty,
            invoiceitemsID: invoiceitemsID,
            delivered_status: delivered_status,
            getinvoiceno: getinvoiceno
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data == "1") {
               //some code
            }

        }); 
    } //end if not match

    //if(match){
    //  alert("matching")
    //}

}
```

Comment: Last part of your question is not understandable. So you can only pass `delivered_qty`. to your server. Can you more elaborate the question?

Comment: i have one html table and can able to add row n number of times.So delivered_qty field have multiple values.If user change any one of delivered_qty 
 field made changes and click update button it should update only the specific delivered_qty.

Comment: Now all the delivered_qty field is updating

Comment: Noted. Can you update the HTML table with the update button too?

Comment: that specific row will identify like delivered_qty and deli_qtydbvalue values are different.Others will be same.

Comment: So you have a one update button ? correct ?

Comment: Thanks for updating the code, will give a try and update as a answer

Comment: yes .when click update button it will call updateData() function .I pasted mu code above

Comment: I have given simple implementation by removing your validations and hoping DB data already inserted into rows. Let me know any clarification you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have a proper code of your application, I just create a simple implementation. Here you don't need that `!match` condition, instead I have use two new variables to keep updated rows only and passing it to the server. Hope this implementation will give you a solution.

```js
function updateData() { //update data
    var delivered_qty = [];
    var delivered_status = [];
    var deli_qtydbvalue = [];
    
    // new variables to keep updated data
    var updatedDelivered_qty = [];
    var updatedDelivered_status = [];
    

    $('.delivered_status').each(function() {
        delivered_status.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('.delivered_qty').each(function() {
        delivered_qty.push($(this).val());
        deli_qtydbvalue.push($(this).attr('data-orginaldbvalue'));
    });

// Only filter out updated rows
if(delivered_qty.length == deli_qtydbvalue.length){
   for(var i = 0; i<delivered_qty.length; i++ )
      if(delivered_qty[i] != deli_qtydbvalue[i]){
        updatedDelivered_qty.push(delivered_qty[i] );
        updatedDelivered_status.push(delivered_status[i]);
      }
}

alert(updatedDelivered_qty);
alert(updatedDelivered_status);

// You don't need if condition here, but use that function that is using to call server
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="itemsdetails" class="itemsdetails" style="clear: both; width: 100%; margin: 1px 0 0 0; border: 0px solid black;">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Id</th>
               <th>Quantity</th>
               <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            
            
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td><input data-orginaldbvalue="10" type="text" class="delivered_qty" value="10"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" class="delivered_status" value="Complete"/></td>
         </tr>
         
           <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td><input data-orginaldbvalue="20" type="text" class="delivered_qty" value="20"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" class="delivered_status" value="Complete"/></td>
         </tr>
         
           <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td><input data-orginaldbvalue="30" type="text" class="delivered_qty" value="30"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" class="delivered_status" value="Complete"/></td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      
      <button onclick="updateData()">Update</button>
```

Comment: inside ajax which data i need to pass? updatedDelivered_qty and updatedDelivered_status right?

Comment: in my requirement i need that if condition becoz user may change or may not be change those fields and click update button.

Comment: for eg :if user made changes i need to call ajax for updation otheriwse alert says no changes are made

Comment: then inside that condition you can write that new function. And yes you should use that new variables

Comment: Sorry, may be you can check where updated_qty has content, if yes then you can call ajax, otherwise alert